# Range of cells in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a question regarding range of cells in VBA in Excel. What I am trying to do is write a VBA code that selects a range of values from an initial value that I supply all the way to the bottom of the column, where the last entry is.

I defined my initial value as:

```
Dim Value_one As Integer
Value_one = 8
```

Now I can't seem to find a code that selects a range of values in a column starting at 8th row to the last cell in that column.
I tried this:

```
Range(Value_one, Value_one.End(xlDown)).Select
```

But it didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try this: `Range(Cells(8, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two** answers:

```
Sub ToTheVeryBottom()
    Dim Value_one As Integer
    Value_one = 8
    Range("A" & Value_one & ":A" & Rows.Count).Select
End Sub
```

will select from row #8 through row #1048576.  However:

```
Sub ToTheLastItem()
    Dim Value_one As Integer, N As Long
    Value_one = 8
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & Value_one & ":A" & N).Select
End Sub
```

will select from row #8 through the last row containing some value.